# in php, switching to another page then to the current page without losing the field values in the current page

Tags: php

I have created a form *receipt.php* in which data is fed in a normal way. After reaching the field called  *mode of payment*, two radio buttons are provided:

1.`DD/cheque`  2.`E-transfer`

On clicking the radio1, dd_detail.php should appear and on clicking radio2, e_trans.php should appear.

After filling the  dd or e-trans details, I need to click on "ACCEPT" button. Then I should get that previous page *receipt.php*  without losing any filled values.

The problem is after clicking on *ACCEPT* button, the field values of *receipt.php* page which I have entered are empty....!!!

What to do for this?

Comment: post the values along, store them in a session, etc ..

Comment: You better go through sessions in php, that will answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP offers session support. It's cookie-based and temporary data is saved on the server. To get started, your first line in PHP needs to be `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Note that it has to be the very first thing in the PHP program - NOTHING, including spaces, can be shown before it, otherwise this will throw an error or wont work.

After that, you can read from / write to a special **$_SESSION** array. For example, beginning of your PHP file might have this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// if user clicks submit, save this for later
if( isset( $_POST['username'] ) ) $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
?>
```

Now, the form field itself should be optionally pre-populated:

`<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>" />`

If your data is fairly manageable, you can dump the entire $_POST variable somewhere into $_SESSION. For example:

`<?php if( !empty( $_POST ) ) $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST; ?>`

After that you could refer to above-saved field as $_SESSION['data']['username']. It's up to you to rework this into your workflow.

Comment: Well... I am already using so many session variables in my form. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Doing forms processing is a rite of passage in PHP. For most programmers, form development stages start from passing values via $_POST, to using $_SESSION, to storing session items in database, and rewriting form fields as OOP classes, and then - bypassing all the complexity by doing everything via AJAX. If there is no strong reason to do this exclusively in PHP, just use JavaScript and fancy HTML.  For example, review all the available widgets here: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/wizard.html

Comment: Thank u sir for the reply... it was too useful for my project.I have used SESSION variables and its working now.But the problem is whenever I reset/refresh the page the field values are not vanishing!!! may I know the reason & any solution for this?

Comment: If you intend to reset the temporarily stored values, come up with your own mechanism for it - and reset the session. unset( $_SESSION['data'] ) could work.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply sir. using SESSION I could retain the text box values,but not the combo box's selected option value. Also I wud like to tell tat Im using AJAX coding on the onclick event of the combo box option value, which then populates another combo box and a dynamic table displayed on my form. Is it possible to retain that generated dynamic table also???

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store them in some `$_SESSION` variable, and then retrieve them from the second script?

**e.g. :**

```
// First script
$_SESSION['myfield'] = $value;
```

---

```
// Second script
$value = $_SESSION['myfield'];
```

Comment: thanks for Ur response... can u please elaborate this... since I am very new to this language...  At which form I need to use this SESSION variable?

Comment: using SESSION its working...But whenever I reset/refresh the page entered field values are not vanishing... any solution for this?